# Importing Two Files into eachother in python

Tags: python, import

I am making a text game in Python and I have two menus, the main menu and the attack menu.  These functions are in two different files.

When I `from attack import *` in my main file to get the attack menu function it works and I can call the `attack_menu()` function.

However, when I go to my attack file and I `from main import *` and then try to call `main_menu()`, it doesn't work.  Is there a way to import both the files into each other and not get an error?

Comment: What if you then want to use your attack menu in another game that doesn't use the same main menu?  Why not have a main "loop" for your game play in another module that imports attack_menu and main_menu separately?

Comment: I assume there is a `main.py` and `attack.py` in the same directory - and you run `main.py` as a script, something like `python3 main.py`?

Answer (score 2):

Circular imports don't work, as you've found out. But there is a second problem lurking. Assuming you run `main.py` as a script, its a module named `__main__`, not `main`. When `attack` imports `main`, it gets a second copy of `main`. `main` imports `attack` again, and you've got your circular reference.

The solution is to take all of the stuff that `attack` wants from `main` and move it into a separate .py file. Lets call it `commonstuff.py`. Now `attack` imports `commonstuff` and `main.py` imports both of the modules and the import works.

`main.py` is the script and `attack` and `commonstuff` are modules.